# gist-vim: change token location

Tags: vim, let, gist

I use [gist-vim](https://github.com/mattn/gist-vim) from mattn together with gVim. Works great and everything but I don't appreciate the auth token laying around in my home directory.

So I started looking around in the [plugin files](https://github.com/mattn/gist-vim/blob/master/autoload/gist.vim) and found the variable called `s:configfile` which the dev sets to `expand('~/.gist-vim')`.

Which makes me believe I can include `let s:configfile = expand('~/some/other/path/gist-vim')` in my `vimrc` to change the location of my token.

But it doesn't work. Is the devs command called again when I run `:Gist`, so my setting gets overwritten? Just thought I need to ask before I start forking and tinkering with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.gist-vim` config file name is [not open for customization](https://github.com/mattn/gist-vim/blob/1164bba797c43b617eff0f0720fd0f76853f2901/doc/gist-vim.txt#L235).

You could ask the plugin author to make it customizable.

Why can't you set the variable in your vimrc though, you may want to know. First, you need to learn about Vim's variable name namespaces, documented at [`:h internal-variables`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#internal-variables).

Variables prefixed with `s:` are variables local to a script. See [`:h script-variable`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#script-variable). Thus you cannot access those from your vimrc.

Comment: Namespaces, these bastards. But modifying `line 22` of `.../autoload/gist.vim` to your desired path works for me. And in regard to you answer, one could replace every occurrence of `s:configfile` with `g:configfile` (of course it should be a more unique name in the global namespace, but just to illustrate), then it should be configurable via the vimrc, I think. Quick question on the sideline: Why does the routine on `line 761` in `.../autoload/gist.vim` --> `(call system("chmod go= ".s:configfile))` have a dot? Is that in regard of the filename or something else?

Comment: That's just string concatenation. Please, I encourage you to consult the documentation `:h eval.txt` for these very basic Vim script questions, thanks!